# create a semi transparent layer shape design using watermark.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a tool using watermark.js (https://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/docs.html) and trying to create a layer as given in the attached picture
[image: Layer shape like this]

[image: Semi transparent Layer on every image]

Whenever I upload an image, this black semi transparent layer shape should apply by default. Sorry for mistakes I am new to javascript.

```
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fortemp/98e67kh2/2/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to make an image transparent, use the `opacity` property.

```
const element=document.getElementById("imageId");

//50% transparent
element.style.opacity="0.5";

//75% transparent
element.style.opacity="0.25";

//25% transparent
element.style.opacity="0.75";
```

Comment: I want to draw a semi-transparent canvas like this curve kind of shape.